# Relationship with a default value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, referential-integrity

Firstly, I know my title is somewhat misleading, but I couldn't think of a better title.

Here is my current relationship

```
CREATE TABLE Events 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    DefaultLocationID INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)

CREATE TABLE Locations
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    EventID INT NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)

ALTER TABLE Events ADD FOREIGN KEY(DefaultLocationID) 
    REFERENCES Locations(ID) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL

ALTER TABLE Locations ADD FOREIGN KEY(EventID) 
    REFERENCES Events(ID) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

My question is knowing that an **Event** can have a list of 0 or more **Locations**, and each **Location** can only be associated with exactly 1 **Event**.

I want the ability for an **Event** to have a default **Location**, but the integrity is that if an **Event** has a **Location** then that **Locations** foreign key must be the same **Event**.

My initial thought was to put a nullable foreign key in the **Event** table *DefaultLocationID*, but it dawned on me that there is no integrity to prevent that **Location** from being associated with a different **Event**.

My other idea was to have a *IsDefault* field on the **Location** table, but that doesn't stop multiple **Locations** from having their *IsDefault* field to true.

How would I enforce this relationship, preferabily without triggers and complex sub-queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your second option, you could put a filtered unique index on:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_DefaultLocation ON dbo.Locations(EventID, IsDefault)
WHERE IsDefault = 1
```

This will allow unlimited non-default locations, but only one default location per event id.

Comment: This looks like it will work exactly how I need, thank you!

Comment: +1 but the following index will do it too: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_DefaultLocation ON dbo.Locations(EventID)
WHERE IsDefault = 1

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov good point, the actual default field is unnecessary in the index since it's in the filter.